# laravel 7 No such file or directory in …/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php

Tags: php, laravel

Output:

```
Warning:  require(/var/www/vhosts/web/httpdocs/vendor/composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/web/httpdocs/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 69
Warning:  require(/var/www/vhosts/web/httpdocs/vendor/composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/web/httpdocs/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 69
Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/vhosts/web/httpdocs/vendor/composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php' (include_path='.:/opt/plesk/php/7.3/share/pear') in /var/www/vhosts/web/httpdocs/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 69
```

[My FTP structure at vendor folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9g2r.png)

[Foundation folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81f7H.png)

Comment: Does your web user have enough permissions to read and execture that file?

Comment: yes, it has 755 permission.